# Next/image component gives error "missing required "width" property." when running it with npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, server-side-rendering

When i run my NextJS app using npm run dev the Image component gives the error `"missing required "width" property"`

To make the app work, i need to set width and height as inline attributes for all Image components in the project.

[image]

**NOTE: I tried setting a width and a height using CSS external file, it did not work. Only setting the inline attributes works.

Full Error

```
error - Error: Image with src "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg/1200px-Flag_of_the_United_States.svg.png" is missing required "width" property.
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/image.js:465:27)
at renderWithHooks (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
at renderForwardRef (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5842:18)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6005:11)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderNode (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
at renderChildrenArray (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderNode (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
at renderHostElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5642:3)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5952:5)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5785:7)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderNode (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
at renderChildrenArray (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderNode (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
at renderHostElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5642:3)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5952:5)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderNode (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
at renderChildrenArray (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderNode (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
at renderHostElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5642:3)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5952:5)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5971:9)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderIndeterminateComponent (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5785:7)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderNode (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
at renderChildrenArray (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
at renderElement (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5971:9)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\sdweikat\mysecond\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11) {
```

page: '/'
}
null

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found out a solution. I added "fill" prop to Image. Then i wrapped it with a div. I can set a CSS class to the div, and that's how i can control the size of the image without inline width and height.

Answer (score 11):

Complementing the accepted solution, in order to avoid defining the required `width` or `height` props, a `fill` prop with value `true` should be added to the `Image` component as:

```
<Image fill={true} src="..." alt="" />
```

There are other settings to keep in mind, such as the parent element `position` value for this solution to work and `object-fit` to preserve the image ratio. Be sure to check the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/image#fill) about `fill`:

Answer (score 3):

### Working Solution

Adding to the above-mentioned solutions.

1. In case of using `fill` you need to wrap your image with a container making its position `relative` else it positions itself with respect to the nearest relative parent (if no parent's position is relative, it positions itself wrt `<body>` )
2. Image takes the height of the nearest parent which has some height. If no parent satisfies this the image height will be 0 (i.e. you won't see the image ).

   ```
   <div className="relative h-20">
      <Image src="/next.svg" alt="Next.js Logo" fill />
   </div>
   ```
3. In some cases the image infers its siblings' height. Consider the below example where the parent div infers its height from the height of the first div.

   ```
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
       <div>Image height is same as My height</div>
       <div className="relative">
          <Image src="/next.svg" alt="Next.js Logo" fill />
       </div>
    </div>
   ```

[**Open the above Code snippets in Code Sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tender-roentgen-v8kzs6?file=/app/page.tsx)

> Note: `fill` sets `position: absolute; top:0; left:0` for the image; Next throws an error if the `position` is changed to `relative` using styles

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to add `fill` property to the Image component

```
<Image fill alt='no image' id={styles.img} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while running tests with Jest/RTL. The `fill` suggestion fixed at first glance, but then, it obviously affected the rendering of the icon when I ran the app. I could have added a wrapper with the width prop set, but I only got this error when running the tests, with a mocked src, so it wouldn't really make sense to change working code.

**TL;DR**: If you can't, or don't want to, change the image tag just for the sake of testing, you can mock it by giving it a real image src, in my case it was an `svg` and it worked:

```
import member from 'assets/img/member.svg'

describe('Component', () => {
  const image = member
  const label = 'Label'
  const value = 'Value'

  test('renders correctly', () => {
    render(<Component image={image} label={label} value={value} />)

    (...)
  })
(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Temporarily add "fill" to the end of the image style. This is a temporary solution to the problem

Answer (score -4):

You have 2 ways:

1. Go to `Image` component and make `width` property non-required.
2. Write `width` manually like
   `<Image src={src} alt='no image' id={styles.img} width={200} />`

Comment: It is already non required

declare const Image: React.ForwardRefExotic.......... {
    src: string | StaticImport;
    alt: string;
    width?: SafeNumber | undefined;
    height?: SafeNumber | undefined;

Comment: You have declared it as a non-required prop. Now you should check that is it non-required when you use it? I mean something like this: <img src={src} width={width ? width : 500} />

Comment: No i did not declare it. It is already declared. I am using Image component from Next/image package. It is a package comes out-of-the-box ready from NextJS framework. 

For your example: <img src={src} width={width ? width : 500} />
I have 2 reasons why i cant use it. 
First, i don't want to use inline attributes at all.
Second, i can't use percentages with inline attributes, because i can't pass strings. For instance width="50%".